# How to import MS Access data into SQL Server using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, import, visual-studio-2013

I have an old MS Access 2003 file that contains information about the personnel on a particular agency. The number of records in that database will range from 800 to 1500.

I want to import those records into my SQL Server database. Is it possible that the importing of data can be done programatically using Visual Basic.net?

If possible, please lend me some help. Thank you.

Here is the structure of the table that I want all the data to be imported

```
     ID
     Fname
     Mname
     Lname
     Address
     Status
```

Comment: VB.NET is not the right tool for this task, consider using SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the MS Access Upsize Wizard (see the following link http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-the-upsizing-wizard-HP005273009.aspx) or the SQL Server Migration Assistant (see the following link for details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313041(v=sql.110).aspx)